# Accessibility: Talkback will read contents of dialog automatically. But NVDA and VoiceOver will not read

Tags: ios, html, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I have implemented Bootstrap(3.3.7) modal for the popup. Talkback will read contents of the modal automatically when it loaded starting from close icon.

But, in VoiceOver it will not. In VoiceOver when modal is opened the focus will move to first interactive elements like button(close button).

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="alertID" tabindex="0" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false">
   <div class="modal-dialog" id="leaving-modal-content" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content leaving-site-content">
          <button aria-label="Close Dialog – button" class="close-icon" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
          <h2 class="headline-text11"><span class="large-modal-text1">Example Title</span>
          </h2>
        <p class="body-copy">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com/" id="link-continue" title="Continue" class="btn btn-red" target="_self">Continue</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" title="Cancel" class="btn btn-red">Cancel</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone can come up with the solution. It would be a great help.
@slugolicious I have got solution from you couple of times.

Please, help me out.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this affects anything, but I don't normally put a `tabindex="0"` on the dialog itself.  I use `tabindex="-1"` so that I can send the focus there programmatically but the user cannot tab to the dialog border itself.

Also, VoiceOver sometimes has trouble with dialogs that are `display:none` > `display:block` rather than `visibility:hidden` > `visibility:visible`.  That is, if you hide your dialog initially with `display:none`, and then unhide it by setting `display:block`, sometimes VoiceOver won't move the focus to the first element in the dialog.  See the "[Additional Gotchas to watch out for](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2018/06/the-current-state-of-modal-dialog-accessibility/)" in Scott O'Hara's blog.  If you initially hide with `visibility:hidden` and then unhide by setting `visibility:visible`, it works better.  But that's only an issue on VoiceOver and only has to do with moving the VoiceOver focus.

However, I think the main problem is that your dialog doesn't have a label or description.  You have a heading in the dialog but the dialog itself should point to that heading.  Just add an ID to the `<h2>` and then refer to that ID in the `aria-labelledby` attribute of the dialog.

If you have other text in your dialog that describes the dialog's purpose, you could put an ID on that description and then refer to it by adding an `aria-describedby` to the dialog too.  Very similar to the `aria-labelledby`.  In the example below, I'll use the "lorem ipsum" paragraph as the description.

Something like:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="alertID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="newID1" aria-describedby="newID2">
  <div class="modal-dialog" id="leaving-modal-content" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content leaving-site-content">
      <button aria-label="Close Dialog – button" class="close-icon" data-dismiss="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </button>
      <h2 id="newID1" class="headline-text11">
        <span class="large-modal-text1">Example Title</span>
      </h2>
      <p id="newID2" class="body-copy">Lorem Ipsum...</p>
      ...
```

Comment: I need a small clarification. Generally when I open the dialog. How should a screen reader read it irrespective of the different screen readers? Should it read the content automatically or on swipe?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything.  If the focus is put on something in the dialog, the dialog title (aria-label) should be read and then whatever contains the focus will be read. The entire dialog does **not** have to be read when it opens.  The user can do that by exploring the dialog.

Comment: I tried the above code for the complete dialog readability. It worked on NVDA but, It didn't work on VoiceOver. Is there any other possible ways for achieving it.